# Find the greatest (largest, maximum) number in a list of numbers

Tags: python, numbers, max

How can I easily find the greatest number in a given list of numbers?

---

<sub>See also [How do I find the maximum (larger, greater) of 2 numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357369) - in that special case, the two values can also be compared directly.</sub>

Answer (score 160, accepted):

What about `max()`

```
highest = max(1, 2, 3)  # or max([1, 2, 3]) for lists
```

Comment: Here's another that is also useful: [find out which variable contains the greatest number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23154821/1447509)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the inbuilt function [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) with multiple arguments:

```
print max(1, 2, 3)
```

or a list:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
print max(list)
```

or in fact anything iterable.

Comment: It's not good to name variables a default builtin python keyword, that overwrites the actual keyword, (you must know that) :-)

Answer (score 18):

> **This approach is without using `max()` function**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,6,7,99,88,999]
max_num = 0
for i in a:
    if i > max_num:
        max_num = i
print(max_num)
```

Also if you want to find the index of the resulting max,

```
print(a.index(max_num))
```

> **Direct approach by using function max()**

max() function returns the item with the highest value, or the item with the highest value in an iterable

Example: when you have to find max on integers/numbers

```
a = (1, 5, 3, 9)
print(max(a))
>> 9
```

Example: when you have string

```
x = max("Mike", "John", "Vicky")
print(x)
>> Vicky
```

It basically returns the name with the highest value, ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Why would you ever not be able to use the max function?

Comment: So I wrote this for those people who prepare for interview, where the question is to find maximum of a list without using max function.If you feel its good for interview please upvote

Comment: If you need the index of the max as well perhaps?  You would then just include the idx var in the for line.

Comment: Don't use `max` as the name of a variable cause it's the name of a builtin.

Comment: this is not correct, if there are only negative numbers on the list, the result will be 0 that you set for max_num.

Comment: @gamusren use max([n for n in your_list if n<0])

Answer (score 11):

Use `max()`

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 5]
>>> max(l)
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`max` is a builtin function in python, which is used to get max value from a sequence, i.e (list, tuple, set, etc..)

```
print(max([9, 7, 12, 5]))

# prints 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually sort it:

```
sorted(l,reverse=True)
```

---

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
sort=sorted(l,reverse=True)
print(sort)
```

You get:

```
[3,2,1]
```

But still if want to get the max do:

```
print(sort[0])
```

You get:

```
3
```

if second max:

```
print(sort[1])
```

and so on...

Comment: Sorting a list is a more complex operation O(n log n) than just getting the maximum value O(n)

Answer (score -7):

```
    #Ask for number input
first = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
second = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
third = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
fourth = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
fifth = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
sixth = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
seventh = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
eighth = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
ninth = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))
tenth = int(raw_input('Please type a number: '))

    #create a list for variables
sorted_list = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, 
              eighth, ninth, tenth]
odd_numbers = []

    #filter list and add odd numbers to new list
for value in sorted_list:
    if value%2 != 0:
        odd_numbers.append(value)
print 'The greatest odd number you typed was:', max(odd_numbers)
```

Comment: 1) there's no reason not to do my_list = sorted([int(raw_input('Please type a number')) for _ in xrange(10)) versus typing extra stuff.  2) you have a list called sorted_list but you don't actually sort it 3) There's nothing in the question asking about filtering out odd numbers only 4) What does this provide that the previous answers 5 year ago didn't (besides answering a question that wasn't asked, and in a less elegant way)