# How do I find the maximum (larger, greater) of 2 numbers?

Tags: python, max

I have two variables `value` and `run`:

```
value = -9999
run = problem.getscore()
```

How can I find out which one is greater, and get the greater value?

---

<sub>See also [Find the greatest (largest, maximum) number in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090175) - those approaches work (and are shown here), but two numbers can also be compared directly.</sub>

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Use the builtin function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Example:
`max(2, 4)` returns 4.

Just for giggles, there's a [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) as well...should you need it. :P

Answer (score 33):

[`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max)

Answer (score 22):

`max(number_one, number_two)`

Comment: Just `max(number_one, number_two)`. The `[]`'s don't add anything useful.

Comment: yeah, those were to show that you should just use to arbitrary numbers, but I can see how that would be confusing

Answer (score 11):

```
max(value,run)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `max(value, run)`

The function [`max`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) takes any number of arguments, or (alternatively) an iterable, and returns the maximum value.

Answer (score 5):

You could also achieve the same result by using a [Conditional Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
maxnum = run if run > value else value
```

a bit more flexible than `max` but admittedly longer to type.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the fun of it, after the party has finished and the horse bolted.

The answer is: `max()` !

Answer (score 3):

`(num1>=num2)*num1+(num2>num1)*num2` will return the maximum of two values.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if you have divisions it rounds off to integer, it would be better to use:

`c=float(max(a1,...,an))/b`

Sorry for the late post!

Comment: What is `b`, and why would the problem involve doing any division?

Answer (score 1):

```
numberList=[16,19,42,43,74,66]

largest = numberList[0]

for num2 in numberList:

    if num2 > largest:

        largest=num2

print(largest)
```

gives largest number out of the numberslist without using a Max statement

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python 3
value = -9999
run = int(input())

maxnum = run if run > value else value
print(maxnum)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1. Custom method

> ```
> def maximum(a, b):
> if a >= b:
>     return a
> else:
>     return b
>  
> value = -9999
> run = problem.getscore()
> print(maximum(value, run))
> ```

2. Inbuilt max()

> ```
> value = -9999
> run = problem.getscore()
> print(max(value, run))
> ```

3. Use of ternary operator

> ```
> value = -9999
> run = problem.getscore()
> print(value if value >= run else run)
> ```

But as you mentioned you are looking for inbuilt so you can use max()