# Finding largest number in list using while loop (python)

Tags: python

I have tried this code:

```
numbers = [1,2,5,8,4,99,3]

x = 0

while numbers[x+1] > numbers[x]: 
    x = x+1

print numbers[x]
```

The output is `8`

Howcan I fix that?

Comment: do you need to use a while loop? max(numbers) will give you what you need if not.

Comment: Your question already has an answer in the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766077/python-finding-the-largest-number-in-a-list-using-forloop-or-while-loop

Comment: I must use a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers = [1,2,5,8,4,99,3]

x = 0
lar = numbers[x]
while x < len(numbers):
  if numbers[x] > lar:
    lar = numbers[x]
  x = x+1
print lar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,5,8,4,99,3]
x = 0 
y = 0

while y != len(a):
    if x < a[y]:
        x = a[y]
    y += 1

print x
```