# How to find out which variable has the greatest value

Tags: python

```
if A > B and C and D:
   print("A wins")
if B>A and C and D:
   print("B wins")
```

How do I check and see which variable contains the largest integer out of the group? Deciding who wins?

Comment: you have the base code there.  You can modify it to test all cases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could test each one:

```
if A > B and A > C and A > D:
```

or you could just test against the *maximum value* of the other three:

```
if A > max(B, C, D):
```

but it appears what you really want is to figure out which player has the maximum value. You should store your player scores in a dictionary instead:

```
players = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D}
```

Now it is much easier to find out who wins:

```
winner = max(players, key=players.get)
print(winner, 'wins')
```

This returns the key from `players` for which the value is the maximum. You could use `players` throughout your code rather than have separate variables everywhere.

To make it explicit: `A > B and C and D` won't ever work; boolean logic doesn't work like that; each expression is tested in isolation, so you get `A > B` must be true, *and* `C` must be true *and* `D` must be true. Values in Python are considered true if they are not an empty container, and not numeric 0; if these are all integer scores, `C` and `D` are true if they are not equal to `0`.

Comment: for some reason its giving me an incorrect answer. It will return that 'B' is the winner when 'D' has most points?

Comment: @user3548949: are your scores strings perhaps? Can you give us a sample of your values? `'100'` as a string will be less than `'90'` because `1` sorts before `9`, for example..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `max()`:

```
if A > max(B,C,D):
    print("A wins")
elif B > max(A,C,D):
    print("B wins")
```

Of course there's also a functional programming way to do this:

```
var_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
max_var = max(zip(names, (map(eval, var_names))), key=lambda tuple: tuple[1])[0]
print("%s wins!" % max_var)
```

The `zip` and `map` transforms the `var_names` list into a list of tuples like `('A', A)`, then it gets the tuple with the highest second item. From that tuple it grabs the variable name.

Comment: Functional solution works great, but there is a typo. The first `names` should be `var_names`, so the line should be changed to: `max_var = max(zip(var_names, (map(eval, var_names))), key=lambda tuple: tuple[1])[0]`

Comment: Note: to get the value of the highest var, rather than the var name, change `tuple: tuple[1])[0]` to `tuple: tuple[1])[1]`