# python 2.7 how to get bigger number between (a, b)

Tags: python, python-2.7

my code is

```
def biggerNumber(a, b):
    if a>b:
     print " Max == b"
    if b>a:
      print "Max == a";            
      return Max;
biggerNumber(10, 20)
```

showing an error global name Max is not defined

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090175/python-find-the-greatest-number-in-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: you didn't defined the Max to return by the way.

Comment: if a>b, then why prints Max==b ?

Comment: i tried by removing max with this code

Comment: `return b if a <  b else a`  would be a slightly nicer way to write the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code is failing is because the `Max` is not defined in the function so when you are returning, it seems unknown to your script, I guess you were trying to do something like:

```
def biggerNumber(a, b):
    maximum = 0
    if a>b:
     print " Max == a"
     maximum = a
    elif b>a:
      print "Max == b"
      maximum = b 
    else:
      print "a == b"  
      maximum = a         
    return maximum

print biggerNumber(10, 20)
```

Comment: @RiteshSingh you can upvote or mark it with a green tick, if it satisfies your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Max is the bigger number, in your case, it should look like this:

```
def biggerNumber(a, b):
    if a>b:
      print " Max == a"
      return a
    if b>a:
      print "Max == b";            
      return b;
    print "Numbers are equal"
    return a
```

Secondly you were missing one condition-numbers are equal.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in one line

```
print max((n1,n2))
```

or in your function

```
def biggerNumber(a, b):
    maximum = 0
    if a>b:
     maximum = a
    if b>a:
     maximum = b
    return maximum;
biggerNumber(10, 20)
```