# How Do I Compare Random Generated Values?

Tags: python, random, generator

Basically i am using a random generator in python to generate a random number 3 times like this

```
for x in range(1,4):
    Card = random.randint(2, 14)
    print(Card)
```

However, now i want to compare the 3 random numbers that were generated to output a message stating the highest number that was generated

i.e if `4, 6 and 10` were randomly generated the message i want outputted would be "Your highest number is 10".

How would i attempt to do that i am stuck can someone please help?

Comment: `cards = [random.randint(2, 14) for _ in range(1, 4)]` stores them in a list, so `cards[0]` is the first one, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Find the greatest number in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090175/python-find-the-greatest-number-in-a-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to hold the highest card, and compare each to it.

```
highCard = 0
for x in rang(1, 4):
    Card = random.randint(2, 14)
    if Card > highCard:
        highCard = Card
    print(Card)
print("Your highest number is ", highCard)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer it really helped, i'd like to just ask for one more thing. Lets say numbers 11-14 (As my range goes from 2-14) i wanted to output strings instead of values for example Jack, Queen, King & Ace how would i do that and how can i edit the code above to account for these strings in the highCard output value so for example if 11 was my highest number instead of saying your highest card is 11 i want it to say your highest card is Jack.

Comment: Use a dictionary that maps numbers to the names.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a list:

```
Numbers = []
for x in range(1, 4):
    Card = random.randint(2, 14)
    print(Card)
    Numbers.append(Card)

print(max(Numbers))
```

For your comment:

You can use dictionaries to do that

```
cards = {11:'Jack', 12: 'Queen', 13: 'King'}

print(cards[max(Numbers)])
```

This will print out 'Jack' if the number generated is 11.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer it really helped, i'd like to just ask for one more thing. Lets say numbers 11-14 (As my range goes from 2-14) i wanted to output strings instead of values for example Jack, Queen, King & Ace how would i do that and how can i edit the code above to account for these strings in the highCard output value so for example if 11 was my highest number instead of saying your highest card is 11 i want it to say your highest card is Jack.

Comment: @TheProKi I editet my answer with how you can do that

Comment: Thanks that works, however i come across an error when the number generated is neither 11, 12, 13 or 14?

Comment: well I didn't write the whole dictionary you can add the other elements by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Using a `generator` for storing the `random.randint` values, and then finding the `max` from it :

```
>>> rand = (random.randint(2,14) for i in range(3))
>>> max(list(rand))
```

One unfortunate side-effect of this is that you won't be able to access the `rand` generator once the `max` function is run on it.

---

Using `list comprehension` to store the values:

```
>>> rand = [random.randint(2,14) for i in range(3)]
>>> rand
=> [4, 11, 5]
>>> max(rand)
=> 11
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
max_Card = -5
for x in range(1,4): 
    Card = random.randint(2, 14) 
    if Card> max_Card :
        max_Card = Card
    print(Card)
```