# How to display in which position a number was entered by input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list and once I sorted it to find the "biggest value", **I need to display in which position this number was entered**.

Any idea how to do it ?

I made this code to receive and sort the list but I have no idea how to receive the initial position of the "data".

---

```
liste = []

while len(liste) != 5:
    liste.append (int(input("enter number :\n")))

listeSorted = sorted(liste)
print("the biggest number is : ", listeSorted[-1])
```

Comment: How do you deal with repeated numbers? Should we assume input numbers are unique?

Comment: You do not need to sort. use `print(max(liste))` to get the max. There are plenty of build-in functions - read about them here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: `list` objects keep no knowledge of previous states. You are going to have to keep track of that yourself

Comment: thank you for answer, repeated numbers are ok, I just need to find the highest value [99, 5, 99] -> biggest value is 99 @jpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Find the greatest number in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090175/python-find-the-greatest-number-in-a-list-of-numbers)

Comment: Oops, missed the 2nd half of the question. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list) a more suitable dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of finding the biggest value of the list by sorting the list, use use the max function:

```
largest_val = max(list)
```

To find the first occurrence of a value in a list, use the `.index` method.

```
position = list.index(largest_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `sorted()` (for more generic cases e.g. if you also want the 2nd, 3rd, etc. "biggest values") :

```
sorted_idx_and_val = sorted(enumerate(liste), key=lambda x:x[1])
# e.g. if liste = [2, 10, 4, 6] then enumerate(liste)   = [(0, 2), (1, 10), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
#                                and sorted_idx_and_val = [(0, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (1, 10)]

largest_val     = sorted_ind_and_val[-1][1]
largest_val_idx = sorted_ind_and_val[-1][0]

second_largest_val     = sorted_ind_and_val[-2][1]
second_largest_val_idx = sorted_ind_and_val[-2][0]
# ...
```

`enumerate()` gives you a list containing tuples of `(index, value)`.

The argument `key` of `sorted()` is a lambda to "preprocess" the key values to sort - here we tell `sorted()` to use only `value` (`x[1]`) from the `(index, value)` elements(`x`).