# Sort dictionary of arrays by highest element

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, where each key maps to an array. I want to sort the dictionary based on the highest value in the array of each key.

For example, the dictionary:

```
{'r': [2, 2], 'e': [4, 5], 't': [1, 1], 'h': [2, 2], 'y': [1, 2], 's': [0, 1], 'a': [0, 1]}
```

should become:

```
{ 'e': [4, 5], 'h': [2, 2], 'y': [1, 2], 'r': [2, 2], 't': [1, 1], 's': [0, 1], 'a': [0, 1]|
```

Comment: Which version of Python is this? CPython versions before 3.6 do not have ordered built-in dictionaries and you would have to use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? See [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value), [Find the greatest number in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3090175/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'r': [2, 2], 'e': [4, 5], 't': [1, 1], 'h': [2, 2], 'y': [1, 2], 's': [0, 1], 'a': [0, 1]}

print({i: d[i] for i in sorted(d, key=lambda x: max(d[x]), reverse=True)})
```

and the result is:

```
{'e': [4, 5], 'r': [2, 2], 'h': [2, 2], 'y': [1, 2], 't': [1, 1], 's': [0, 1], 'a': [0, 1]}
```